# i.MX8MP: Which .dts file addresses are accessible to both processors at once?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded, cortex-m

Which of these memory areas can be used simultaneously by two cores - Cortex M7 and Cortex A53? And how can I do this? What address do I need to specify for the mmap function on the Linux side so that the function returns a pointer and I can write to memory using it?

And what address should I use on the side of the M7 coprocessor so that I can also write and read there?

```
&resmem {
/* global autoconfigured region for contiguous allocations */
linux,cma {
compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
reusable;
size = <0 0x2c000000>;
alloc-ranges = <0 0x40000000 0 0x80000000>;
linux,cma-default;
};
 
m4_reserved: m4@0x80000000 {
no-map;
reg = <0 0x80000000 0 0x1000000>;
};
 
m7_ddr_alias: m4@0x10000000 {
no-map;
reg = <0 0x10000000 0 0x1000000>;
};
m7_itcm: m4@0x7E0000 {
no-map;
reg = <0 0x7E0000 0 0x20000>;
};
m7_dtcm: m4@0x800000 {
no-map;
reg = <0 0x800000 0 0x20000>;
};
 
vdev0vring0: vdev0vring0@55000000 {
reg = <0 0x55000000 0 0x8000>;
no-map;
};
 
vdev0vring1: vdev0vring1@55008000 {
reg = <0 0x55008000 0 0x8000>;
no-map;
};
 
vdevbuffer: vdevbuffer@55400000 {
compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
reg = <0 0x55400000 0 0x100000>;
no-map;
};
 
rsc_table: rsc_table@550ff000 {
reg = <0 0x550ff000 0 0x1000>;
no-map;
};
};
```

P.S.I know about RPMsg/remoteproc drivers, but I really need to hardcode reading and writing data directly into memory without using any rpmsg, etc.

Comment: It probably has to be done at the scfw level and not through the kernel.  Otherwise, the Linux could trample on M7 memory.  The secure boot and boot locking will isolate the elements by default.  For example 'RM: Resource management Service' has 'sc_rm_mr_t' type to partition memory.